# Laravel 5.6: Failed queued jobs not retrying using Horizon

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6, laravel-horizon

I am currently running Horizon using Redis on my Homestead VM.

I have an example queueable mailable that looks a bit like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

// ... imports ...

class WelcomeEmail extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function build()
    {
        sleep(10);
        throw new \Exception("TEST JOB FAILED!");
    }
}
```

I am running Horizion successfully using a Supervisor configuration as described here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/horizon#deploying-horizon

```
[program:horizon]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=php /home/ubuntu/code/myapp/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=vagrant
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/home/ubuntu/code/myapp/storage/horizon.log
```

When running the above mailable like so:

```
new WelcomeMail();
```

a new job is created and fails after about 10 seconds as expected.

My issue is that Horizon doesn't seem to retry jobs that failed. By default it should be retrying after 90 seconds (according to `config/queue.php`), for 3 times (according to `config/horizon.php`).

So why are my failed jobs not retrying?

Comment: Try to run `php artisan cache:clear` and restart your horizon process. If this doesn't help try to run the mail without the exception and see if passes, because I'm not sure if you have a `user=forge` in the homestead for the supervisor config, it might be called vagrant or something else.

Comment: `php artisan cache:clear` does not seem to solve the problem.

The supervisor is running correctly. What I showed above was just an example. I updated it to avoid confusion. If it wasen't, the horizon dashboard wouldn't even show up.

The mail works fine & passes without the exception. It just fails to retry jobs.

Comment: Have you found a solution?